# d3 Nested SVG plots differently in firefox than in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I've seen versions of this question but they haven't helped me to solve this issue. I am using d3 with a nested svg, here is the code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

var nestedSVG = svg.append('svg') 
        .attr("width", innerWidth)
        .attr("height", innerHeight)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

The nestedSVG makes an inner height/width so that some plots get cutoff appropriately. This works perfectly in firefox, but not in Chrome. When I scroll over nestedSVG in firebug it shows the appropriate dimensions, but when I scroll over nestedSVG in javascript console in chrome the dimensions are altered. This results in the plots being different. Any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: what are width/height/innerwidth/innerheight assigned to? It could be a percentage issue.

Comment: width = 960, height = 570, innerWidth = 860, innerHeight = 570, margin.left = 50, margin.top = 20

Comment: it looks like your innerheight + margin.top might exceed your height?

Comment: changed innerHeight to 500, no change.

Comment: what are the dimensions in chrome?

Comment: Solved it. Instead of using translate as an attr I had to append it like so:  nestedSVG = nestedSVG.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); -- Was not applying the transform directly on "g" elements. Thanks for the help regardless I realize that I probably did not put enough info into the OP.

Comment: The ability to set a transform on an `<svg>` element is new in SVG 2 and is not yet widely supported. Firefox does support it, IE does not currently, not sure about other UAs.

Comment: This is actually an important issue, @RobertLongson. Do you want to turn that into an answer for posterity?  After all, the main justification for adding transform to SVG elements is because people expect it to work and it doesn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to set a transform on an `<svg>` element is new in SVG 2 and is not yet widely supported. Firefox does support it, IE does not currently, not sure about other UAs.

Comment: I'm actually still having trouble finding a solution, how does one cutoff elements if they cannot specify an innerheight/width that cuts off all plots that are outside of the inner dimensions. Transforming g elements still has them residing in the outer dimensions.

Comment: Perhaps I should just ask a new question. Thanks for the information.

Comment: The SVG2 spec doesn't define it in enough detail, but it hopefully will soon. See http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2014Dec/0003.html for some of the things that are currently undefined.