# d3 Workaround for svg transform in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, d3.js

I've created an inner dimension to cut off plotting in d3. Here is the code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

var nestedSVG = svg.append('svg') 
        .attr("width", innerWidth)
        .attr("height", innerHeight)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

This works fine in firefox. But I've learned that chrome does not support svg transforms like this (and it isn't working in chrome). Is there a workaround so that I can transform nestedSVG?

Comment: Why not append "nestedSVG" to a div instead?

Comment: Transforms on the <svg> element is explicitly disallowed in SVG 1.1, which means the transform there is silently ignored in most browsers. SVG2 will try to solve this, but it's not yet defined exactly how it should work. The workaround is to append a <g> element that gets the transform instead, works everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`x` and `y` attributes on your nested SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElementXAttribute) to create a translation of coordinates.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

var nestedSVG = svg.append('svg') 
        .attr("width", innerWidth)
        .attr("height", innerHeight)
        .attr("x", margin.left)
        .attr("y", margin.top);
```

For more complicated transforms, you would use a parent or child `<g>` element and transform that, [as you mentioned in comments to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27263831/3128209).