# d3 Animate chart when hovering over a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I'm rather new to d3 so please go easy on me.

I have finally gotten a donut chart to work. When I hover over slices of the donut chart, they separate successfully, and display in the way I would like. I have added a new table to the page, and the data in the table mimics the data represented by the chart. I was wondering if there would be a way to animate the slices in the same way that they do when I hover over one, when I hover over it's corresponding table's entry.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

P.S, If there is a much easier way to populate the table, which I assume there is, feel free to share that information as well!

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vh8tgq6/) is the fiddle link!

```
$('#testtable tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
     $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

This is how I'm hovering over the table now,

```
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .attr("d", arcOver);
            })
            .on("mouseout",function(d){
                div.html(" ").style("display","none");
                d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                   .duration(100)
                   .attr("d", arc);
            });
```

And this is hovering over the slices.

Answer (score 4):

Build the table with d3 and then bind `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to the `<tr>`s.  Also, no need for jQuery here, let d3 handle it all.

```
// column headers
var keys = ["Date","Value","Rate","Type"];

// add the headers 
d3
    .select("#testtable")    
    .append("tr")
    .selectAll(".head")
    .data(keys)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .attr("class","head")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });    

// add the rows
d3
    .select("#testtable")
    .selectAll(".dataRow")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
    .attr("class","dataRow")
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
        // make the row red
        d3.select(this)
            .style("background-color","red");
        // find your path and transition
        var path = paths[0][i];
        d3.select(path).transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .attr("d", arcOver);
    })
    .on("mouseout",function(d,i){
         d3.select(this)
            .style("background-color","transparent");
        var path = paths[0][i];
        d3.select(path).transition()
        .duration(100)
        .attr("d", arc);
    });

// add table data
d3.selectAll("#testtable .dataRow")
   .selectAll("td")
   .data(function(row) {
       return keys.map(function(d) {
           return {value: row[d]};
       });
   })
   .enter()
   .append("td")
   .html(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vh8tgq6/3/).

Comment: that is awesome! this works perfectly. I'm trying to figure out how to make the opposite work now as well, when hovering over a slice, the table will highlight. I assume this is just adding the highlighting into the mouseover event for the arc, but I'm trying to figure out how to map to the table. Any ideas?

Comment: hey! looks like i'm learning a little bit. I've got it selecting and highlighting all the rows when i mouseover the arc, time to figure out how to just pick the right data.

Answer (score 0):

For Future viewers,

@Mark answer is a correct solution, but I ran into some problems translating the svg in Chrome and IE regarding this issue: 
[d3 Workaround for svg transform in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283610/d3-workaround-for-svg-transform-in-chrome)

add a translation after line 44 in Mark's fiddle,
Something like: 
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + chartWidth/2 + "," + chartHeight/2 + ")")

and remove from line 31 to translate the  element instead of the entire 
Then adjust the var svg variables to g, and it should work in Chrome. IE is a different story