# How to translate SVG and all its children

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have been playing with this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/8k8ggpcn/4/

Majority of it is not my code, but from line 330-345 I have added, tried to, the ability to move the SVG by a certain amount. But this is not working. I can't seem to figure out why.

I have tried using D3. So added an ID of `mainSVGContainer` to the SVG at the start :

```
svg = d3.select("#svg1")
    .append("svg").attr('id', 'mainSVGContainer')
```

And used this to translate :

```
 d3.select('#mainSVGContainer').style('fill','blue').attr("transform", "translate(0 "+difference +")")
```

`Difference` is an integer worked out before this call, its around 130. But this doesn't seem to work. It gets written to the DOM but doesn't look like it's affecting the SVG.

I have tried with vanilla JavaScript :

```
var svgContainer = document.getElementById('mainSVGContainer');
 svgContainer.offsetLeft = 1000;
```

This doesn't work either

And I have tried with inline JS to alter the styling :

```
 svgContainer.style.left = 1000;
```

Still no luck. I presumed it was due to it being an SVG element but I tried doing the same with the container of this SVG which was a div and no luck.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `svgContainer.style.left = 1000;` does *work*, it's just that you also need to have `svgContainer.style.position = 'absolute';` set. You could also use `style.padding` or `style.margin` to accomplish the same without needing to set `position` to `absolute`.

Comment: @JSBob cheers for that, the padding worked :) But doesn't move it up like I wish to do. Do you know why I can't do it via the D3 way ?

Comment: It does work, just not in Chrome. [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) has the ability to apply a `transform` to SVG elements, but it does not appear that Chrome supports this. If you want to set it using d3, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283610/d3-workaround-for-svg-transform-in-chrome) question might help. @thatOneGuy

Comment: No wonder. I need to get in the habit of debugging in multiple browsers. Thank you

Comment: Found out a work around. Appended a g element to the svg and translated that :) I shall add an answer as it may help others :)

Comment: It's worth noting, that according to the spec's [attribute index](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) the `transform` attribute doesn't apply to the `svg` element. Therefore, the behavior is not to blame on Chrome, which seems to comply with spec. @JSBob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JSBob and others from the following :

- [d3 Workaround for svg transform in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283610/d3-workaround-for-svg-transform-in-chrome)
- [d3 Nested SVG plots differently in firefox than in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263831/d3-nested-svg-plots-differently-in-firefox-than-in-chrome)

I found out Chrome, along with other browsers, don't support the translation of SVG elements. So, as a work around, I appended a `g` element to the `SVG` and translated that :

Appending g :

```
 svg = d3.select("#svg1") 
    .append("svg").attr("height", h)
    .attr("width", w)
    .append('g')
    .attr('id', 'mainSVGContainer')
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("class", "graph-svg-component")
```

Translating g :

```
d3.select('#mainSVGContainer').transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", "translate(0 "+(-difference) +")")
```

Added the transition so you can see before and after :)

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/8k8ggpcn/7/